# Как восстановить таблицу в БД mysql командой?

Tags: unix, mysql, linux

Есть хостинг iphoster. Там стабильно раз в 1-2 месяца рушится целостность одной таблицы, а именно `dle_online`. Я ее востановливаю в phpmyadmin'е, и все нормально.

Хочу сделать скрипт на крон, чтобы каждую ночь проводил восстановление или оптимизацию таблицы. Я так понимаю, команда

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -ddb "REPAIR TABLE `dle_online`"
```

Как-то так?

Comment: =) может все дело в название таблицы?))

Answer (score 1):

обычно в пакете с другими клиентскими программами (он может называться *mysql*, *mysql-client* и т.п.) идёт программа `mysqlcheck`.

она принимает «стандартный» для *mysql*-клиента набор опций и параметров (указание хоста, пользователя, пароля, базы данных, таблицы и т.п.). к слову, всё это можно, конечно, задать через конфигурационный файл `~/.my.cnf`.

в том числе она принимает опции `--repair` и `--auto-repair` (для автовосстановления без дополнительных подтверждений). примерно так:

```
$ mysqlcheck --user=пользователь --password=пароль \
  --repair --auto-repair база-данных таблица
```

---

часто имеется и символическая ссылка на эту же программу под именем *mysqlrepair*. её использование полностью идентично вызову *mysqlcheck* с опцией `--repair`.